# When connected to wired internet connection, have the packets usually been transmitted wirelessly at any point?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

In my network technologies class, there is a fellow student that has claimed: "It is highly likely that much of the data you access every day was transmitted wirelessly at some point before it reached you. Especially if the data came from over seas."

When connected to a non-mobile or wifi connection, I suspect that this is not particularly true, even for the overseas part (I know there are cables across the oceans), but I can't find any good resources to back me up.

Am I right? Any authoritative resources on the subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really very much an opinion based question, but I'd say this is unlikely.

Certainly a chunk of information is transmitted wirelessly before it gets to the receiver, but I'd put to you that unless you have an interest in a developing company MOST of the content WOULD NOT go through a wireless connection.

The reason is this - Most websites and large players are going to need large volumes of bandwidth.  In this respect, Wireless technologies are a lot more constrained then cable based technologies.  For a start, you can send more data down a fiber cable then wirelessly - and if you need more capacity you simply run more fibres.

Most popular content would be distributed from servers.  A service provider will generally look for reliability - and WIFI does not tick this box.  Similarly the servers will typically be located in data centers in hubs - which are connected to the backbone through fibre (or at least copper).

This logic is compounded in that - normally (but certainly not always), providers using "non-commercial" grade backhaul are behind NAT, so not likely to be servers.  Similarly, commercial grade wire free backhaul is expensive and limited relative to colocated servers.

Where your friend may have a bit of traction might be in P2P applications and user submitted content - I would imagine a fair chunk (most ?) end users [ignoring corporates with security concerns and hard-wired connections] would come from machines connected wirelessly - it just seems wireless is a lot more ubiquitous then ethernet for "in-home" connections.   (The same may also be true if you are using something like TOR)

That said, about 1/3rd bandwidth in the USA is used by Netflix.  Netflix certainly don't use Wireless for backhaul.   Thats just Netflix.    Then there are all the CDN networks who distribute and mirror content - certainly these will be located at well-connected data centers, so not wireless.  (Think Amazon, Google, Akamai)

Of-course, if you are in a "developing nation", very often parts of the backhaul connections are wireless - because often 4g networks are the only available methods of connecting (no legacy infrastructure, no business case for fibre etc).

Comment: Yes, the question would pertain to a developed country in a non-remote rural area. I don't think saying some guy submitted some content over a home wifi network qualifies for the sake of the validity of his argument. The data gets to you (on a wired connection such as DSL or cable) from a web server that is completely wired in almost all cases, correct?

Comment: Correct.   The key thing is that for large connections or dense areas, copper or fibre is invariably cheaper (and arguably more reliable) then wireless connectivity.

Comment: Who argues that wireless is more reliable?

Comment: It can be - I've been to a network operators group conference with wireless players, and a number of them say their wifi is more reliable then other offerings.  Similarly, I recall purchasing capacity off satellite a LONG time ago - certainly the SLA was better then for an end user DSL type connection.  Also, in my experience, TV and radio stations are more reliable then DSL connections, and they travel wirelessly, so there is an argument to be made that commercial grade wireless connectivity, with "non free spectrum" signals can be more reliable then copper connections...

Comment: Oh, and when you say "certainly a chunk of information is trasmitted wirelessly..." what do you mean by that?

Comment: And, of-course, in a natural disaster like an earthquake (I live in NZ, there was an earthquake in Christchurch - which was not built to handle it) wireless connectivity can be better.

Comment: By chunk I mean "some amount of".  I do know of some people who have run servers off wireless connections (I think they needed their head examined, but they did it nonetheless).  Also, some stuff will come from overseas over satellite, and backhaul from less dense areas may be wireless as well.  The point is the majority of traffic won't be wireless.

Comment: Historically, satellite uplinks used to provide high bandwidth ( but also high latency ) compared to trans oceanic cables, so at some point, it would have been somewhat likely that trans oceanic traffic would use such a route.  With the proliferation of fiber, that isn't really true these days.  Also there is a *big* difference between a satellite relay and say, unencrypted local wifi, which I'm guessing is the kind of thing this classmate was alluding to.